# Scrolldown function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a single page mock gym website and i'm using a scroll down function on the nav bar buttons to the relevant sections. I'm also trying to use it on a link in the 'classes' section of the page to scroll down to the contact section of the page. However, when after putting in the js code it takes me to the top of the page instead. the error i'm getting in the console is : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null but i don't understand how to fix the problem from similar issues on stackoverflow. Below is the code and the section i'm talking about is the first card in the classes title 'spin' which a 'call or email to book now' link. I would be greatful for any help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>FITT GYM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--nav bar-->
    <header>
      <div class="logo-text">
        <h1 class="logo-text"><span>FITT GYM</span></h1>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-bars menu-toggle"></i>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="about-button">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="classes-button">Classes</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="pt-button">PT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="contact-button">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <!--nav bar-->
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/woman-lifting-barbell-1552249.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="barbell">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/adult-athlete-body-bodybuilding-414029.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/photo-of-woman-jumping-on-box-2294403.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!--about-->
<div class="about-section">
<h2 class="about-header">About FITT GYM</h2>
<p class="about-para"><i>FITT Gym is a berkshire based gym designed to help individuals achieve their fittness goals. 
Founded in 2014, FITT gym has been recognized as one of the top UK gym brands for it's high intensity workouts,
results driven personal trainers and for being one of the most socialable gyms to go to. With a state of the art facility 
FITT gym makes your workout experince a comfortable one as well as endless equipment to train with.</i>
</p>
</div>
<br>

<div class="classes-section">
  <h1 class="classes-header">Classes</h1>
  <p class="classes-about"><i>The most popular reason why people become come to FITT gym is our classes! see what's on below:</i></p>
  <body>
    <div class="py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row hidden-md-up">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/athlete-bike-black-and-white-cycle-260409.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Spin</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1" id="spin-card-text">The ride of your life to ensure you can ride mountains.</p>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class=".contactBtn">Call or Email to Book Now</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/man-in-blue-shorts-carrying-brown-exercise-equipments-116079.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Kettle Bells</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1">Russian style kettle bell workout to make you tougher than ever.</p>
                <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/there-women-in-a-yoga-session-917732.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Yoga</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1">An experince that will clean your mind and keep you healthy.</p>
                <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/people-boxing-inside-gym-1862785.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Boxing</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1">Fight your way through this tough workout with our experienced trainers.</p>
                <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/person-holding-barbell-841130.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Crossfit</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1">Increase your power in our crossfit bootcamp and you'll be as strong as the hulk</p>
                <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-block">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/man-working-out-2294361.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <h4 class="card-title">Core Conditioning</h4>
                <p class="card-text p-y-1">The core conditioning class will shake up your abs.</p>
                <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<section class="pt-section">
<h2 class = "pt-header">Personal Training</h2>
<p class="pt-about"><i>If you feel you need a 1:1 personal training session, then our trainers here at FITT can offer sessions that a personally designed for your personal goals and needs. 
  Whether you want to build muscle, lose weight, or just feel better, we can help achieve that with our experienced trainers.
Click below to book a session:</i></p>

      <div class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row hidden-md-up">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/action-active-adult-body-416754.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <h4 class="card-title">1:1 Session</h4>
                  <p class="card-text p-y-1" id="spin-card-text">A serious workout that will direct you towards your goals. Prepare for intensity and achievement!</p>
                  <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/man-and-woman-holding-battle-ropes-1552242.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <h4 class="card-title">2:1 Session</h4>
                  <p class="card-text p-y-1">A workout for you and a friend or family member to get FITT together. Achieveing goals together forms bonds that last forever! </p>
                  <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/man-and-woman-doing-yoga-1882004.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <h4 class="card-title">1:1 Meditation</h4>
                  <p class="card-text p-y-1">Learn to focus, clear thoughts and feel mentally stronger. Have a 1 to 1 session with a meditation master and reach enlightenment.</p>
                  <p><b>Call or Email to Book Now</b></p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </section>

      <br>


<section class="contact-section">
      <h1 class="contact-header">Contact</h1>


<footer class="footer-distributed">

            <div class="footer-left">

                <h3>FITT GYM</h3>

                <p class="footer-links">
                    <a href="#" class="link-1">Home</a>

                    <a href="#">About</a>

                    <a href="#">Classes</a>

                    <a href="#">PT</a>

                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </p>

                <p class="footer-company-name">FITT Gym © 2020</p>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-center">

                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    <p><span>Epic Road</span> Windsor, <br> Berkshire, <br> United Kingdom, <br> SL8 8QE</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <p>01344 865467677</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    <p><a href="mailto:support@company.com">info@fittgym.com</a></p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="footer-right">

                <p class="footer-company-about">
                    <span>About FITT Gym</span>
          FITT Gym is a berkshire based gym designed to help individuals achieve their fittness goals.
                </p>

                <div class="footer-icons">

          <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/FSAscot/"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/fsascot/?hl=en"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/fsascot?lang=en"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>



                </div>

            </div>

    </footer>
    </section>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;

}

 body {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;

}


#carouselExampleSlidesOnly{
    z-index: -5;
}



#classes-heading{
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
}

.card-text {
    color: #0c0c0c;
}

.btn-btn-primary {
    align-items: center;
}

#classes-header {
    color: white;
}

header{
    background:  #0c0c0c;
    height: 66px;
}

header * {
    color: white;
}

.header .logo {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    margin-left: 7em;

}

header .logo-text {
    margin: 8px;

}


header ul{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;


}

header ul li {
    float: left;
}

header ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 21px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header ul li a:hover{
    background: #3c3b3d83
}



header .menu-toggle{
    display: none;
}


.page-wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
}




.about-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

.about-para {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color:white ;
    text-align: center;
}

.classes-header {
    text-align: center;
    color:white ;
}

.classes-about {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color:white ;
    text-align: center;
}

.pt-header {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

.pt-about {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}


.footer-distributed{
    background: #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    padding: 55px 50px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;

    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  rgb(31, 66, 163);
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
  font-weight:400;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #222;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
  font-weight:400;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  rgb(32, 59, 178);
    text-decoration: none;;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a:before {
  content: "|";
  font-weight:300;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links .link-1:before {
  content: none;
}

/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}

.contact-header{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```
function smoothScroll(target,duration){
    var target = document.querySelector(target);
    var targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var distance = targetPosition - startPosition;
    var startTime = null;

    function animation(currentTime){
        if(startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
        var timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
        var run = ease(timeElapsed, startPosition, distance, duration);
        window.scrollTo(0,run);
        if(timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
        console.log('timeElapsed : ' + timeElapsed + 'duration: ' + duration);

     }

     function ease(t, b, c, d) {
         t /=d / 2;
         if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
         t--;
         return -c / 2 * (t *(t - 2) - 1) + b;
     }


    requestAnimationFrame(animation);

}

var aboutBtn = document.querySelector('.about-button');
var aboutSection = document.querySelector('.about-section');
var classesBtn = document.querySelector('.classes-button');
var classesHeading = document.querySelector('.classes-header');
var ptBtn = document.querySelector('.pt-button');
var ptSection = document.querySelector('.pt-section');
var contactBtn = document.querySelector('.contact-button');
var contactSection = document.querySelector('.contact-section');
var cobBtn = document.querySelector('contactBtn');




aboutBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.about-section', 1000);
});

aboutSection.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.about-button', 1000);
});

classesBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.classes-header', 1000);
});

classesHeading.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.classes-button', 1000);
});

ptBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.pt-section', 1000);
});

ptSection.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.pt-button', 1000);
});

contactBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.contact-section', 1000);
});

contactSection.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.contact-button', 1000);
});

cobBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    smoothScroll('.contact-section', 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please create a codepen to better illustrate an issue

Comment: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", when you try to get a dom element which doesn't exist (wrong selector) you get `null` and I think you are trying to add a listener to that returned element(null) so you need to make sure you are selecting the correct element, the problem is I don't see any addEventListener() method calling in your code?! pls provide the related JS code to that

Answer (score 0):

```
var cobBtn = document.querySelector('contactBtn');
```

should be

```
var cobBtn = document.querySelector('.contactBtn');
```

because `"contactBtn"` is a class name, I don't know about your code but I think you then add an event listener to that codeBtn element, which was returning null
in your case because it can't find an element with the tag name `"contactBtn"`

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
>   [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: still not getting a soloution. Is it anything to do with the bootstrap cards I've implemented maybe?

Comment: well you have href attribute set on your contact button to the current page and that what makes it takes you to the top of the page, change it to `href="javascript:void(0)"`